# Javascript / REGEX: Delete a specific Text (word) starting with a specific letter inside a String with words separated by spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text, replace

I know this can quickly be done with Regex:

I got string like:

> "Alpha OmegaS Sheol Gehena GSSaga Serekali"

I wanna remove words that Starts with s.

So I should have:

> "Alpha OmegaS Gehena GSSaga"

What have I tried?

Something like: `str.replace(/^\\S/,"") //This NO GOOD.`

The thing is I understand REGEX very well, but somehow REGEX does NOT understand me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You specified a lower case "s" where as the text sample you give only contains words beginning with an uppercase "S". Are you looking to remove words starting with both lower and uppercase "s"?

Comment: insensitively targeting the case will be a prudent move...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
str.replace(/\bs\S+/ig,"")
```

**Explanation:**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  s                        's'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------

i is for case-insensitive
g is for global
```

Comment: You'll need to add the `g` modifier to remove all occurrences. Currently your solution will only replace one.

Comment: Amazing bro... now at least Regex has understood me. Thanks again.