# Remove a word starting with x in a sentence

Tags: java, regex

How to remove a word in java which is starting with the "http" in a sentence?

**Input:** Mag 4 earthquake in Liechtenstein. Buildings from Middle Ages said to do better in quakes than their modern friends. http://t.c\u2026;

**Output:** Mag 4 earthquake in Liechtenstein. Buildings from Middle Ages said to do better in quakes than their modern friends.

Comment: Please provide more input, like what have you tried so far, what is not working, etc.

Comment: See [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590612) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678666) for a starting place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure of the code i write but you can find something like this:

```
String data="blah blah blah";
int index = data.indexOf("http");

String subString = str.substring(index, data.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

`s/ http[^ ]*//g`

At least, that will work in sed. Tailor to your regex engine.

Comment: with his question, i'm wonder if he understand regex

Comment: I can find specific word but i don't know how to remove just this word starting with "http"

Comment: @deadManN well regex is a tag of the question...

Comment: @user3161635 if you want to just remove the first word using this regex, remove the 'g' at the end. If you want to remove an arbitrary word that you have found the index of, see deadManN's answer.