# JavaScript: How to get index of the occurrence of a certain character that is immediately after another certain character?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this array of tweets:

```
var arr = ['@userone Hey man, whats popping', 'Shoutout to @usertwo haha']
```

How would I make get rid of the mentions and only contain the message? So like:

```
var newArr = ['Hey man, whats popping', 'Shoutout to haha']
```

Here's what I can come up with

```
if (tweet.includes('@')) {
  var atIndex = tweet.indexOf('@');
  var spaceIndex = // index of the nearest space after @
  var strToReplace = tweet.substring(atIndex, spaceIndex);
  tweet = tweet.replace(strToReplace, '');

}
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript / REGEX: Delete a specific Text (word) starting with a specific letter inside a String with words separated by spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590612/javascript-regex-delete-a-specific-text-word-starting-with-a-specific-lette)

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.map(e => e.replace(/(?:^|\W)@(\w+)(?!\w)/g,"") )
```

Done in one line :) ... demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/b3vf0w9a/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is your friend here.

```
   var arr = ['@userone Hey man, whats popping', 'Shoutout to @usertwo haha'];

    arr.forEach(function(element,index) {
        arr[index] = element.replace(/@[A-Za-z0-9]*\s/, "");
    }

    console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

building on @Abdennour...

```
var newArr = arr.map(e => e.replace(/@\w+\s+/,"") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ['@userone Hey man, whats popping', 
           'Shoutout to @usertwo haha'
          ];
var i = 0, at_pos, sp_pos, str_rep;
while(i<arr.length) {
  at_pos  = arr[i].indexOf('@');
  sp_pos  = arr[i].indexOf(' ', at_pos);
  str_rep = arr[i].substring(at_pos, sp_pos+1);
  arr[i]  = arr[i].replace(str_rep, '');
  console.log(arr[i]);
  i++;
}
```

OR simply you can use regular expressions like

```js
var arr = ['@userone Hey man, whats popping', 
           'Shoutout to @usertwo haha'
          ];
var i=0;
while(i<arr.length){
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/\@[^\s]*\s/g, '');
  console.log(arr[i]);
  i++;
}
```